# Can you narrow down entity framework one to many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, one-to-many

I have three lists in an object that all use the same variable, right now to build the one to many relationship I'm using:

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Object>()
    .HasMany(u => u.ListA)
    .WithRequired()
    .HasForeignKey(s => s.ObjectId);
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Object>()
    .HasMany(u => u.ListB)
    .WithRequired()
    .HasForeignKey(s => s.ObjectId);
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Object>()
    .HasMany(u => u.ListC)
    .WithRequired()
    .HasForeignKey(s => s.ObjectId);
```

The list item has a type property that corresponds to list A B and C, Is there a way to further refine those statements to add something similar to :
    where (t=>t.type == A)

Object has 3 lists that all hold the same object type the only difference between the list items is their type property. 
list object properties:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public EntryType Type { get; set; }
public string Value { get; set; }
public int SequenceNumber { get; set; }
public virtual StatusReport StatusReport { get; set; }
public int StatusReportId { get; set; }
```

Comment: it's not really clear what you are asking based on the code snippet you posted.  what is "everything", and what exactly do you mean by saying that 3 lists are using the same variable?  I think you need to expand your question detail a bit.

Comment: It would help to see sample class definitions. It's not clear if `ListA` etc. are different classes or how many collections `Object` has.

Comment: So you are saying that `ListA` is a collection of related objects and you want to add a constraint that they must all have a certain property value? I don;t think you can do that in SQL without custom triggers, so I doubt EF has such a mechanism.

Comment: @DStanley yes that's exactly what I'm trying to do, I wasn't sure if there was a way to do it but I just wanted to make sure. Thank you

Comment: I'm not an NHibernate fan, but in NHibernate you can easily do this with formula properties.